# Android: Access SharedPreferences from a home widget in another class

Tags: java, android, widget, sharedpreferences

I have an activity that runs a method in another class that access sharedpreferences. I want to make a widget that can run the same method from a button click. It works as long as the app is open in the background, but if it is closed, the app crashes when I press the button on the widget.

I am fairly certain that this is because of the context I need to access sharedpreferences, and I tried passing the context through from the activity and the widget separately but it is not working.

Basically, how can I access sharedpreferences from a widget when the method is in another class?

Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static Context context;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void panicFromView(View view){
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Methods.panic(prefs);
    }
}
```

Widget Code:

```
public class PanicWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String CLICK_PANIC = "PANIC";
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.panic_widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PanicWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(CLICK_PANIC);

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.panicButton, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (CLICK_PANIC.equals(intent.getAction())){
            panicFromWidget(prefs);
        }
    }

    public void panicFromWidget(SharedPreferences prefsIn){
        Methods.panic(prefsIn);
    }
}
```

Methods:

```
public class Methods {

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MainActivity.context;
    }

    public static void panic(SharedPreferences prefsIn){

        //loops through contacts
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            String contactKey = "contact-sms" + i;
            String contactNo = getContact(contactKey, prefsIn);

            //sends sms only if contact number exists
            if (!contactNo.equals("")) {
                sendSMS(contactNo);
            }
        }
    }

    //returns contact number from contact name
    public static String getContact(String key, SharedPreferences prefsIn){
        return prefsIn.getString(key, null);
    }

    //sends SMS to contact number
    public static void sendSMS(String phoneNo){
        try{
            String msg = "test";

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);

            Toast.makeText(getAppContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code of how you are passing context from widget and activity.

Comment: show the code that u have to acces sharedpref plzz

Comment: Added the code. I tried passing the sharedpreferences through instead, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it actually does work. Somehow my sharedpreferences got cleared without me knowing so it was throwing a nullpointerexception.